# Android Studio Font or Typeface enumeration

Tags: android, list, fonts, enumerate, typeface

I have read android.graphics is much better that java.awt, which wouldn't get packaged anyway. Well it's got me beat! Can anyone tell me how I can enumerate, reduced to font/typeface families and not a different entry for **bold**, *italic* etc) **all** the fonts or Typefaces available to my app, including those that I create myself, not just a list of the /system/fonts folder?

A seemingly easy endeavour with java.awt but cloaked in mystery in android.

I have searched and. as a result, tried many suggestions, no matter how esoteric, found on here and elsewhere but still I am bereft of an straightforward method.

Why? I am writing apps for assistance in SpLD (**Sp**ecific **L**earning **D**ifficulies or often called dyslexia) and the choice of the correct font/typeface to enable the user the maximum readability in their terms. These people have a brain wiring that, in some cases, allows them to be the architects of large, complex buildings but makes it difficult for them to perform trivial tasks like spelling, short term memory and distinguishing eg **b** from **d**. The apps are games but they developed for a serious intent from a SpLD professional's view.

In this case, I would like them or their supervisor/tutor to be able choose the best font/typeface by presenting a font selector.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is not the place for tutorials. You should edit your question to show what you've tried and what error or unexpected response you get back.

Comment: OK. I definitely do NOT want a tutorial. I will just enumerate the font files in the android system fonts, obtain their properties and list them as variants according to their families. Then I can just add my own creations to them. They, at least, are special designed for SpLD in the UK. I will seek advice on their global suitability from teachers in other English speaking countries. Thank you for your welcome and advice. @ScottyB :)